# Keras - TensorBoard does not save the logs file

Tags: python, keras, tensorboard

As an example of network, I used the first example [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/#examples)

I would like to use tensorboard with this network. After read this [documentation](https://keras.io/callbacks/#tensorboard) about how to use TensorBoard, I added these commands to the code:

```
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
TensorBoard("Directory path that contains the log files")
```

The output sounds correct:

```
Out[3]: <keras.callbacks.TensorBoard at 0x7f14730e79b0>
```

But there is nothing in the directory...

What I did wrong ?

Here is the complete code:

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

# Generate dummy data
import numpy as np
x_train = np.random.random((1000, 20))
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(np.random.randint(10, size=(1000, 1)), num_classes=10)
x_test = np.random.random((100, 20))
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(np.random.randint(10, size=(100, 1)), num_classes=10)

model = Sequential()
# Dense(64) is a fully-connected layer with 64 hidden units.
# in the first layer, you must specify the expected input data shape:
# here, 20-dimensional vectors.
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=20))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          epochs=20,
          batch_size=128)
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=128)
TensorBoard("Directory path that contains the log files")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the callback to model.fit:

```
tb = TensorBoard('log_dir')
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          epochs=20,
          batch_size=128,
          callbacks=[tb])
```